# Contains and best match first then others, C# or Javascript

Tags: c#

I am having one string list and want to filter values on the basis of search filter (split on space) and order the results as per given filter.

```
List<string> all = new List<string>() { "Consultant", "QA Manager", "HR Manager", "Database Manager", "Architect", "Project Manager", "Project Coordinator" };
var filter = "Project Manager";
var  filterList = filter.Trim().Split(' ');
var matchProfiles=  all.Where(o => filterList.Contains(o));
```

Now results are in order "QA Manager", "HR Manager","Database Manager", "Project Manager", "Project Coordinator".

Here is the problem, I require the result in order as given in filter and it should be Project Manager first then Project Coordinator then manager specific profiles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want your filtered strings in the order of the filter words, one possible solution is filter them in a loop in order,something like this:

```
List<string> all = new List<string>() { "Consultant", "QA Manager", "HR Manager", "Database Manager", "Architect", "Project Manager", "Project Coordinator" };
var filter = "Project Manager";
var filterList = filter.Trim().Split(' ');
List<string> matchProfiles = new List<string>();
// First do exact match
matchProfiles.AddRange(all.Where(o => o.Contains(filter) && !matchProfiles.Contains(o)));

foreach (string filt in filterList)
{
    matchProfiles.AddRange(all.Where(o => o.Contains(filt) && !matchProfiles.Contains(o)));
}
//Result: "Project Manager,Project Coordinator,QA Manager,HR Manager,Database Manager"
```

Comment: @NaumanSharif I think you don't understand. The loop is made only in the filter words. So, if the filter is "Project Manager", there would be done just twice, despite there are thousands of records